# Twisted trial error on code that uses twisted.python.log

Tags: python, logging, twisted

I can't seem to log to stdout and run trial on the same bit piece of code.

temp.py

```
from sys import stdout
from twisted.python.log import startLogging
startLogging(stdout)

class Foo(object):
    pass
```

temp_test.py

```
from twisted.trial import unittest
from temp import Foo

class FooTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    pass
```

output

```
2015-07-27 17:45:06-0400 [-] Log opened.
2015-07-27 17:45:06-0400 [-] Unable to format event {'log_namespace': 'twisted.logger._global', 'log_level': <LogLevel=warn>, 'fileNow': '/Users/james/Dropbox/code/demo/server/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/python/log.py', 'format': '%(log_legacy)s', 'lineNow': 210, 'fileThen': '/Users/james/Dropbox/code/demo/server/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/python/log.py', 'log_source': None, 'system': '-', 'lineThen': 210, 'log_logger': <Logger 'twisted.logger._global'>, 'time': 1438033506.184351, 'log_format': 'Warning: primary log target selected twice at <{fileNow}:{lineNow}> - previously selected at <{fileThen:logThen}>.  Remove one of the calls to beginLoggingTo.', 'message': (), 'log_time': 1438033506.184351}: Invalid conversion specification
2015-07-27 17:45:06-0400 [-] Log opened.
```

Why is this code failing? It looks like it's trying to start logging twice?

---

I did notice that `twisted.python.log` has been replaced by `twisted.logger`; it should just be a wrapper around that. The `Logger` class doesn't seem to have a direct analog to `startLogging(stdout)` though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the problem here is [a bug that has already been fixed in Twisted](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ticket/7916), with the formatting of the warning string here.

However, the real problem is that you are starting logging twice, once by running `trial`, which sets up its own log observers for catching logged exceptions, and once by calling `startLogging` at module scope.  You'd get a similar error if you used [the new API for doing this](http://twisted.readthedocs.org/en/latest/core/howto/logger.html#starting-the-global-log-publisher), so switching to `twisted.logger`, while a good idea in the long run, isn't really related.

The proper solution is usually just to not start logging yourself; let `twistd` or `trial` do it for you.  If you do need to start it yourself, it should be in the context of a `main` function which is only run when starting your program "for real", outside of `trial`, for example.